# How to Adjust the size of text in the TextView?

Tags: android

I have look to a lot of tutorial to how to adjust a textView but i don't really a
understand how?

i am using a simple Activity that have a TextView that i went it to be the bigger as possible
That is the class

```
public class Zoom extends Activity
{
private String productName;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.zoom);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        productName = intent.getStringExtra("ChoosenMed");

        TextView productNameTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.prodcutNameZoomTextView);
  productNameTextView.setText(productName);

 }



}
```

Now what i went is to adjust the productNameTextView to fit the screen each time when i use this activity, like when the word its big the text will be smaller then when the word its smaller.

Thank for helping

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `android:textSize=100dip` this will increase your text size.

If you want your TextView size to be increased, try providing the layout_width and layout_height in some dip value. This should work

Comment: I think it should be 100sp, not 100dip

Answer (score 0):

try some thing like this 
android:layout_height="80dp"

u can keep changing the dp to get the required TextView size same to layout_width="70dp"
hope this answers your question